# Meaning of the letters following bus numbers in usbmon

Tags: usb

```
$ sudo ls /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/
0s  0u  1s  1t  1u  2s  2t  2u  3s  3t  3u  4s  4t  4u
```

According to the usbmon [documentation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt), `u` is a superset of the `t` format. What is `s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the driver source code
[mon_text.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/mon/mon_text.c#L699) 
we can see in function `mon_text_add()` where this `/sys` file is created: (loosely)

```
snprintf(name, NAMESZ, "%ds", busnum);
debugfs_create_file(name, 0600, mon_dir, mbus, &mon_fops_stat);
```

and if we follow `mon_fops_stat` we see it defined in
[mon_stat.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/mon/mon_stat.c#L61)
where the open routine is `mon_stat_open()` which creates static data for
any later read with

```
snprintf(sp->str, STAT_BUF_SIZE,
 "nreaders %d events %u text_lost %u\n",
  mbus->nreaders, mbus->cnt_events, mbus->cnt_text_lost);
```

The comment at the start of the file says *This is the 's' or 'stat' reader
which debugs usbmon itself.*

So it seems if you read this `/sys` file you will get a line with the current
number of users of usbmon. The other 2 fields don't seem to be updated in
the 4.5 kernel.

```
 nreaders 0 events 0 text_lost 0
```